# How to wmv video file in alfresco

Tags: ffmpeg, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am using [Media Viewer](https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/media-viewers) add on to preview documents. For video files I am using FFMPEG as described in Media Viewer configuration page. It  is able to convert for .avi files. But when I preview .wmv file it says `could not load thumbnail list` and the page is stuck. When I reload all I get is black screen and only volume is audible no video is available.

How to preview wmv video file ?

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: I am getting `could not load thumnail list` whenever I preview wmv video file. How to preview wmv file

Comment: what's the mimetype of the video in Alfresco? Doy you have ffmpeg transformations errors in your log?

Comment: @alfrescian MS WMV video stream

Comment: that's not an mimetype - e.g. video/x-ms-wmv is a mimetype.
You can see the mimetype on the content property of your node in the node-browser

Comment: @alfrescian It is video/x-ms-wmv. From node browser :contentUrl=store://2014/5/6/19/58/ab4c19ae-ccdd-42dc-8fb1-f1e69f1f5c45.bin|mim‌​etype=video/x-ms-wmv|size=21304100|encoding=UTF-8|locale=en_US_|id=5302

Comment: try to execute the transform manually:
ffmpeg.exe -y -ss 10 -i ${source} -f image2 -vframes 1 out.png

Comment: I converted the file offline using ffmpeg and it is converting fine but it is not converting inside share

Comment: well, then there should be sth. in your log...